# If $f(x,y) = x(y^2 - x)^2 + y^5$ and $g(x,y) = y^4 + y^2 - x^2$, what would be the resultant of these two polynomials?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

If $f(x,y) = x(y^2 - x)^2 + y^5$ and $g(x,y) = y^4 + y^2 - x^2$, what would be the resultant of these two polynomials? How does one compute the resultant in the first place when dealing with more then one variable? Thanks!

Comment: Are you studying about resultant?

Comment: Indeed but only with one variable.